# Infer function return type from function argument

Tags: typescript

Having this code:

```
const handleNodes = (node: Node | Node[]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    return [{}];
  }
  return {};
};
```

I'd like to have this result:

```
handleNodes([{}]) // infer that this returns an array
handleNodes({}) // infer that this returns an object
```

How can I do that? I tried to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), but with no success.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of arguments does not vary on each function call, you can use [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) as such

```
type DemoNode = {
    id?: string;
};

// Declare possible function calls with return types
function handleNodes (node: DemoNode): DemoNode
function handleNodes (node: DemoNode[]): DemoNode[]

// Implementation
function handleNodes (node: DemoNode | DemoNode[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    return [{}];
  }
  return {};
}

const res1 = handleNodes([]);
    // ^? const res1: DemoNode[]
const res2 = handleNodes({});
    // ^? const res2: DemoNode
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7AcogJtAvFA3gKCkKgEs0B+ALigGdgAnYgOwHMBuPAX3bwHofYIAYwA2AQzrQwiatWIAjYdABmAV0aDgxRIyiDRw4dSgB3YsAAWUCcBV0doSNTyr1m7VHOjGaRagxGACkZ0CCo4JD8IAEowhBQQ5zUNLR1Pb18QwOCMWIiQgG0AXRiBPIwivF5+AEl4MEV4CEZgUTdGRNcUjy8fCEiskNz4jCgAH1LhiCKo3AISJSgAgEE6OlEQADpiahW1kCCQqJn8IisIGzsofJwOQvZCDjnrWx0b9ke8QW1aM+oARig2DSvX6AWm9yIfCgAD0yJ9vsBfgAmQHddJ9TIBG5RCGEKGwoA)